# UTF to ASCII for comparison in JAVA

Tags: java, utf-8, ascii, string-comparison

I have a list of strings and i want to compare it with "singleArgument" , i dont want it to be case sensitive so i made a method to make it lowerCase but also i dont want special characters to mess up comparison so if im looking for "ščž" singleArgument can be "scz"

```
case noCaseSensitive:
  final String patternSourceILike = (String) singleArgument;
  verdict = buildPattern(patternSourceILike.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
    .matcher(((String) resolvedValue).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
    .matches();
  break;
```

this i have for no case sensitive comparison.

If i convert string from utf8 to ascii and than compare it turns special characters to unknown characters.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve. Are you asking how get _"ščž"_ resolved to _"scz"_ (i.e. remove any accents)? Please update your post to include an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why you'd want to do this, since removing diacritics from letters makes them completely different letters, but you can use [java.text.Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) for this: normalize the text to its [canonical decomposition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFD), then replace all "not ascii letters" with empty strings to strip out all (now separate) diacritics.

```java
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String []args) {
     String input = "\u0161\u010D\u017E"; // ščž
     String canonical = Normalizer.normalize(input,  Normalizer.Form.NFD);
     String ascii = canonical.replaceAll("\\W", "");
     String output = String.format("%s, %s", input, ascii);
     System.out.println(output); // "ščž, scz"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hardly an unusual requirement, and the opening sentence of the specification for the `Normalizer` class that you linked to explains why the OP might want to do it.

Comment: Unless explained, I'm not going to guess at whether their reasons are sensible or not. If you're already familiar with unicode normalization and canonical forms, sure you can probably come up with lots of reasons to do this. If you clearly haven't even heard of normalization, those odds steeply drop steeply. Op didn't state their reasons, so no one know _why_ they want to do this.